# How to get fully qualified name of parameter value in a method

Tags: java, reflection, eclipse-jdt

I have to get the fully qualified name of the method parameter.

For example:

```
public void display(Custom1 a, Custom2 b) {
    String x = a.getValue();
    String y = b.getValue();
}
```

Here, `Custom1` and `Custom2` are in `com.test.resource` so I need to get the value like

```
com.test.resource.Custom1
```

I am in need of this in my eclipse plugin.. I used `IMethod.getParameterTypes()` . The result is like

```
QCustom1;
```

How can I get the fully qualified name of the method parameter?

```
String[] parameterNames = iMethod.getParameterNames();                  
ILocalVariable[] parameterTypes = currentmethod.getMethod().getParameters();                
for (int j=0; j < parameterNames.length; ++j) {         
    System.out.println("parameter name:" + parameterNames[j]);
    System.out.println("parameter type:" + parameterTypes[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load the corresponding method using reflection and get the parameter value one by one.

```
    if(method.getName().equals(iMethod.getMethodname())){

                          /**
                           * cheking whether the length of the parameter are equal
                           */
                        if(method.getParameterTypes().length==iMethod.getParam().length){

                            /**
                             * getting the fully qualified name of the selected method paramater value
                             */
                            Class<?>[] paramvalue=method.getParameterTypes();

                            for(int p=0;p<paramvalue.length;p++){

                                /**
                                 * checking whether teh parameter are same for loading teh datastore
                                 */
                                if(paramvalue[p].getSimpleName().equals(temp)){

                                    String fullyqualifiedname=paramvalue[p].getName();


                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
             }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried this logic after loading the class, It works!

Answer (score 3):

Here follows an alternative if you want to avoid reflection and prefer a pure JDT solution (in an Eclipse plug-in, the reflection API is not very friendly).

In order to decode the JDT codified type name, you should use the [Signature](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FSignature.html) class.

**Resolving the type(s) name(s) parts**

An important step is to resolve the method declaring [IType](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIType.html) object to be able to recompute the full name with this type imports. Then the [#resolveType(simpleName)](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IType.html#resolveType(java.lang.String)) method should help you. Its use is subtle.

**Building the full name from the parts**

Here is a code to go from a parameter type codified name to the full name, it takes the first solution while resolving the names from the declaring type:

```
ILocalVariable parameterVariable = ...
IType declaringType = method.getDeclaringType();
String name = parameterVariable.getTypeSignature();
String simpleName = Signature.getSignatureSimpleName(name);
String[][] allResults = declaringType.resolveType(simpleName);
String fullName = null;
if(allResults != null) {
    String[] nameParts = allResults[0];
    if(nameParts != null) {
        fullName = new String();
        for(int i=0 ; i < nameParts.length ; i++) {
            if(fullName.length() > 0) {
                fullName += '.';
            }
            String part = nameParts[i];
            if(part != null) {
                fullName += part;
            }
        }
    }
}
return fullName;
```

Getting the full name from a simple name (non JDT codified) is done the same way without using the Signature class. The solution for the result type is the same, [here](http://bdulac.github.io/eclipse/platform/#jdt-decode-signatures) is the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant from [bdulacs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777064/6634600). It makes more use of the [Signature](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FSignature.html) class. As a result, the source code is even shorter. It still avoids reflection and is a pure JDT solution.

As the original answer, this solution is a code to go from a parameter type codified name to the full name, it takes the first result of `declaringType.resolveType()` while resolving the names from the declaring type:

```
ILocalVariable parameterVariable = ...
IType declaringType = method.getDeclaringType();
String name = parameterVariable.getTypeSignature();
String simpleName = Signature.getSignatureSimpleName(name);
String[][] allResults = declaringType.resolveType(simpleName);
if(allResults != null && allResults[0] != null) {
    return Signature.toQualifiedName(allResults[0])
}
return null;
```